# how to filter out words in python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

For example:

```
item =['the dog is gone', 'the dog and cat is gone']
words= ['dog','cat']
```

I want to be able to filter out the `dog` and `cat` so it would read:

```
item=['the  is gone', 'the   and  is gone']
```

```
item1=[] 
for w in words:
   for line in item:
      if w in line:
         j=gg.replace(it,'')
         item1.append(j)
```

I get the following:

```
['the  is gone', 'the cat and  is gone', 'the  and dog is gone']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looping over all lines for each word and appending the replaces. You should switch those loops:

```
item1 = [] 
for line in item:
    for w in words:
        line = line.replace(w, '')
    item1.append(line)
```

Note: I altered some code

- changed `gg` to `line`
- changed `it` to `item`
- removed the check if `line` contains `w` as that is handled by `replace`

`replace` does not know about word boundries. If you want to remove entire words only, you should try a different approach. Using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

item1 = [] 
for line in item:
    for w in words:
        line = re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % w, '', line)  # '\b' is a word boundry
    item1.append(line)
```

Comment: when do this other other words it takes apart words ie. good -> od  but go==good gives  false comparison.

Comment: @user1753878 updated the answer with replacing of full words only

Answer (score 2):

You might use this approach instead:

```
item =['the dog is gone', 'the dog and cat is gone']
words= ['dog','cat'] 

item2 = [" ".join([w for w in t.split() if not w in words]) for t in item]

print item2

>>> ['the is gone', 'the and is gone']
```

Comment: This is significantly faster! micro seconds vs milli seconds for my use cases